# Why does my loop never stop when using vector .size() as the stop condition?

Tags: c++, loops, vector, iteration

```
vector<int> x (100.0);
//int vsize = x.size();

for(int i = 0; i < x.size(); i++){
    x.insert(x.begin() + i, 100 - i);
    cout << "Index " << i << ": " << x[i] << endl;
}
```

I want to add 1 into x[99], 2 into x[98], 3 into x[97], ...99 into x[1] and 100 into x[0].

However, the loop never stops. When I use `int vsize` instead, it will work. Can someone explain to me what is going on here? I am aware of how `.capacity()` works with vectors. Is this whats happening here? Does the vector just keep increasing itself?

Comment: Use a debugger and step line by line to check what happens, then you can find the answer yourself :)

Comment: your code in it's self is correct you only need to a `if statement` which will stop the execution if number being pushed is smaller than 0. Just make a extra variable which will compute the number first and then check if its smaller than 0 then `break`.

Comment: What do you think `vector<int> x (100.0)` does?

Comment: @peter what do you mean? It sets the size. I'm just learning this topic. Obviously.

Comment: @Fallen, my professor forbids us to use break or continue. He said never use continue and only use break in switch statements. He has a PhD so I assume he knows lol

Comment: @Descode - It was necessary to ask, given that you initialised the vector by passing a floating point value (not a valid type for a size, but can be converted to an integral type). In any event, the size is initially `100`, and each call of `x.insert()` increases `x.size()`.  Starting with `i = 0` and `x.size()==100` and incrementing both in every loop iteration, when would you expect `x.size()` to be less than `i`? [The real explanation is more complicated, since `x.size()` is an unsigned type and overflowing an `int` gives undefined behaviour, but I'll leave that alone].

Answer (score 3):

Because you are inserting a new element every time in the loop, so it never stops.

It seems like instead of inserting, you want assigning. So:

```cpp
for(int i = 1; i <= x.size(); i++){
    x[100 - i] = i;
    std::cout << "Index " << i << ": " << x[i] << endl;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

@Descode if using `break` statement is a problem then please look into this

```
vector<int> x(100);

for(int i = 0;i<100;i++){
    x[i] = 100-i;
    std::cout << "Index " << i << ": " << x[i] << endl;
}
```